# A number with 6 distinct digits which get multiplied by 5 if we move the last digit to front

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle, decimal-expansion

There is a number with 6 different digits, if we pick the last digit of that number and place before that number we got $5$ times our number.

How to find such a number?

Comment: You should only have one question per post. Also, have you tried to solve these yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: 1. $142857$ works.
2. I suspect the answer is not an integer, which is strange for a puzzle.

Comment: I removed the second part, which was [reposted separately](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571503)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number can be written $10x+y$, where $10000<x<100000$ and $0<y\le 9$. The modified number is then $100000y+x$ and so the equation is
$$
100000y+x=5(10x+y)
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
99995y=49x
$$
Since $99995$ is a multiple of $7$, we have
$$
14285y=7x
$$

> Now $7$ divides $14285y$, but doesn't divide $14285$. So $7$ divides $y$ and the condition $0<y\le 9$ gives $y=7$ and $x=14285$.

Note that the information that the number has different digits is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is ABCDEF then FABCDE = 5*ABCDEF or in other words: 5(100000A + 10000B + 1000C + 100E + 10E + F) = 100000F + 10000A + 1000B + 100C + 10D + E.

Hint: Try subtracting one from the other.

2)James age now = y;

John age now = x;

How long ago it was when James was Johns age: m =  ???? something to do with x and y ?????

i) y = 2(x - m)

ii) y = 28

iii) m = ???? something to do with x and y and maybe 28 if y = 28 ?????

Comment: How can I now m?because I want x

Comment: Today, James is $28$ years old, but $m$ years ago, James was $x$ years old. Now write $m = \ldots$ where the only things after the equals sign $=$ are $x$ and/or known numbers.

Comment: So $m=2$ then we get that $x=16$

Comment: No that is wrong, but why? I dont get it

Comment: Note that this half of this question has been reposted as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571503/age-puzzle-problem

Comment: How can you know m?   Well, James is 28 now.  How many years ago was he x?  I'm so and so now.  Some years ago I was some other age.  How many years ago was I that age if I'm this age now.